# emacs fonts from ssh not as good as locally installed

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, centos, emacs

How can I have the same emacs fonts and antialiasing configuration that I have in my local Ubuntu 12.04 also working when I open an emacs session via ssh to a CentOS 5 system?

EDIT: I didn't get an answer for this and it's still bothering me. I have emacs 24 installed, so I thought it should have been easy to have good quality fonts with antialiasing enabled...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RemoteEmacs#toc9 (How to make sure fonts on the remote application are in sync with what you have on your local display?).

> By isolating all font-settings into the X11 server’s resource database. It is quite a versatile system, where generic settings can conditionaly be made. **xrdb**(1x), the program to access the database, filters via **cpp**(1) preprocessor, and sets some *defines* to choose behaviour upon. [tekonivel](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/tekonivel) does this, and also sets all the colours into the XRDB too. With X11 the xrdb doesn’t need to run on the same machine as the X11 server, so all configuration can be made from the same machines where the Emacs will be running from, if need be. Tools exist to ask which fonts the X11 server has (f.ex. **xlsfonts**(1)), thus these preferences may be programmed.

Comment: Generally answers are preferred to be self-sufficient. Could you please add the relevant info from the link that solves the problem to your answer?

Comment: I followed the instructions under xrdb and did a `xrdb -merge ~/.Xdefaults` but there is no change in the fonts...

Comment: Did you restart `X` after that?

Comment: on the client I did, on the server, I can't, I don't have permissions.